# Is it possible to enable login as any user feature for production

Tags: grant-login-access

This is possible for sandbox orgs. Is this possible for production org? Before raising the case with salesforce i would like to know if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

This feature Available in:  Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited and Developer Editions

> This feature is available to be enabled by the system administrators
>   without the need of logging a case with support starting with the
>   Summer '15 release, but when an organization has been upgraded from
>   Professional Edition into Enterprise edition, this feature will need
>   to be manually enabled by support. Please create a case to request it.
>
> After the Summer '15 release system administrators should be able to
>   activate this feature without the need of logging a support case.
>   Please follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Your Name | Setup | Administration Setup | Security Controls | Login Access Policies.
>      Or in Enhanced User Interface Click Setup | Administer | Security Controls | Login Access Policies.
> 2. On the "Login Access Policies" page, enable Administrators Can Log in as Any User.
> 3. Click Save.

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Enabling-Organization-Admins-Can-Login-as-Any-User) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks Devendra for providing inputs. I dont see this option in my org. Though its a enterprise edition org. Any idea why is it happening. Do I have to go with case approach or Am I missing something. Accepting your reply as solution.

Comment: Yes, you can open case for this. Feature requested: - "Enables Org Admins to log in as any user without having access granted by the users​"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
This feature will work on production as same as sanbox/Developer organisation.